# ELB Setup for SSL is not working for apache redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have configured ELB with SSL certificate.
Listener configuration for ELB is shown below --
443 (HTTPS, Certificate: www.xyz.com) forwarding to 80 (HTTP), 80 (HTTP) forwarding to 80 (HTTP)

Domain Registrar setup with Godaddy 
CNAME record entry 
www

There is no entry for A-Name record with my domain xyz.com

Apache .htaccess setup

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.xyz.com [R=301,L]
```

When I go to browser and type xyz.com it is not redirecting it to https://www.xyz.com
When I type www.xyz.com, it is not redirecting it to https://www.xyz.com

I do not have any VirtualHost setup on ELB EC2 instances.

Can someone help me out to resolve this problem.

Comment: You didn't share your actual domain name, so you'll have to tell us exactly what happens when you go to "xyz.com" or "www.xyz.com".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this better under the existing virtual host configuration directive:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !www.xyz.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.xyz.com [R=301]
```

Comment: I did this settings and I am getting -- Server error
The webpage at http://www.xyz.com/ is currently unavailable. It may be overloaded or down for maintenance.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 503 (Service Unavailable): The server is currently unable to handle the request. This code indicates this is a temporary condition, and the server will be up again after a delay.

Comment: This rule works as was tested. You need to check your other rules so to see that they don't interfere with this one.